# show command when starting with "<register name>

Tags: vim, vi

As a begginer in vim I would like to have visual feedback when operating with registers. And by default when pasting from registers, namely when you start a commmand with the " and then specify register name and then the command like "p", you don't have any clue niether if you type the register name correctly nor if the following command have any typo. Is there a way to make vim show the full command when you start it with "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a kind of a solution - formatting the statusline in order to include current used register. Typing a command that uses a register will now display the mentioned register name in the according column in the satusline. It is achieved with including %{v:register} in the satusline.

Answer (score 0):

Well have a look at `:h showcmd`. I am afraid, that there is no other possibility as far as I know. This shows the whole entered command.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin to do exactly that:

https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo

> Peekaboo will show you the contents of the registers on the sidebar when you hit " or @ in normal mode or  in insert mode. The sidebar is automatically closed on subsequent key strokes

If you simply want to see the contents of your registers, you can use `:reg`

Check `:h :reg`

Comment: I don't have privileges to install plugins on the server.  Thank you for you answer anyway.

Comment: @monsieur-tout-le-monde if you can add `%{v:register}` to `&statusline` then you can install plugins.

Comment: @romainl I load my vimrc with -N -u command line arguments. Then installing and loading a plugin from a custom path would require probably adding it in my vimrc file. Yes , it is doable. Thanks.